# Using HTTP Authentication with a C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, authentication, webrequest

I want to make a web request to a page that needs authenticating. How would I go about doing this? I found something that said possibly to use the Credentials property, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assign a new `NetworkCredential` instance to the `Credentials` property:

```
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Mehrdad", "Password");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but ikutsin's answer setting the "Authorization" header explicitly with Basic auth info did work for me.

Comment: Both methods (credentials and adding header) are works. But i don't really get which one is better and why?

Answer (score 22):

Basic auth example:

```
public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest req, String userName, String userPassword)
{
    string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
}
```

http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/at3/Forcing-basic-http-authentication-for-HttpWebReq.html

Comment: Good point here.  The extra chattiness that this avoids can also be a performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to authenticate automatically with.  This will use the credentials of the currently logged on user.

```
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```