# C# make wget request

Tags: c#, wget

I have this wget request:

```
wget --http-user="user" --http-passwd="password"
www.example.com
```

In http request i wrote url address, but i don't know where to put login iformation.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTTP Authentication with a C# WebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707888/using-http-authentication-with-a-c-sharp-webrequest)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
string page;
using(var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    page = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/");
}
```

?