# Password protect a file on the internet

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, security

I have a file which I would like to access from my computer using *a program*, not a browser. But I don't want anyone else to be able to see it. So I want to send a password along with the request.

How do I set the file up to require a password? (Any type of file. Not necessarily a web page which has a codebehind.)

I searched, but all I could find is instructions about setting up login pages. That's *not* what I want.

EDIT

I see posts like [Using HTTP Authentication with a C# WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707888/using-http-authentication-with-a-c-sharp-webrequest) which use `NetworkCredential` - But it seems that to use Basic Authentication, one needs to use a Windows User account. This is not secure. Is there a way to create a password (+ username if needed) *only for a specific file or folder* ?

Comment: You could set your web server to basic http authentication and then use the `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` class to access it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707888/using-http-authentication-with-a-c-sharp-webrequest

Comment: @Hinek That's exactly what I want to do - But the link only shows how to _access_ it with a password. How do I set up the page to require it?

Comment: What kind of web server are you using? IIS? Apache?

Comment: @Hinek IIS.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @CloseVoters - Care to explain why?

Comment: In IIS Manager select the folder that contains your file, double click Authentication and disable Anonymous + enable Basic. Then go back and double click Authorization Rules, remove All Users and add your user ... basically.

Comment: @Hinek Thanks. But I'm still looking for simple password protection - not user-based protection.

Comment: I think you should detail your question ... so far, no one (including me) understands what you want to know. Where is the difference if your program submits a username and a password or just the password?

Comment: @Hinek Thanks for all the input. I don't care if I have to send a username. I just thought that you were referring to creating a new Windows login username. (Because "Authorization rules" _doesn't have_ any place for a password.) Now I found what (I assume) you were referring to - which is ASP.net -> Users. Unfortunately, this is a hosted website and I'm getting an "the configuration section for this feature has been locked and is read-only" error. You can convert your comment to an answer, though. It seems to be exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your web server to basic http authentication and then use the `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` class in the client program to access it: [Using HTTP Authentication with a C# WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707888/using-http-authentication-with-a-c-sharp-webrequest)

On the server: In the IIS Manager select the folder that contains your file, then:

- configure Authentication (disable Anonymous + enable Basic)
- create a user
- configure Authorization Rules (remove All Users and add your user)

Maybe this question helps you, too: [How do I create a user account for basic authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373497/how-do-i-create-a-user-account-for-basic-authentication)

Comment: +1. Thanks. From [an answer to the question that you linked to at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373497/how-do-i-create-a-user-account-for-basic-authentication/22513386#22513386) , it seems that what I'm looking for is impossible - The only way to have a file behind a password is by adding a Windows user account.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of authentication mechanism on the server.

There are a few possibilities:

1. Pass around username/password in the header of the request (make sure to use HTTPS and probably hash the password);
2. Use the user agent to 'check' what / who it is (less recommended, easy to forge).

I would go for 1:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
wr.Headers["username"] = ...
```

On the server end, use a `HttpHandler` or something like that to check access to the file and pass the right one to it.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: +1. But I would still like a simpler answer that will work for an arbitrary file type.

Comment: Then set up regular authentication, like proposed in the comments. This will however give you no extra control then just the password-checking.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for simple password protection, not user-based protection.

Comment: This answer will serve that purpose as well. Instead of the words "username/password", use the words "application key/pin". Now its no longer user-based as you will pass that only from your "app".